Build typescript website into single html file
I have a html page, including some css and typescript which I use to prettify some logs.
I would like to bundle all the files (css, html, javascript generated from typescript) into a single file, so that the prettified logs are fully selfcontained in a single file and can be exchanged easily.
I have looked into webpack, but stuggle with telling webpack to transform the template, so that the compiled typescript, and referenced css files are inlined. I am not tied to webpack, inc ase anyone knows a better tool for the job.
The main reason for my index.html below is that my build so far was to run tsc -w while building out the components.
MWE:
This should be enough of a MWE skeleton to get the issues across. I would like <link rel="stylesheet" href="..."> and <script src="..."> to be inlined (also to run tsc on the typescript files which generate the js)
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>LogView</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="logview.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="eyesymbols.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DropDownButtonSymbolFonts.css"> <!-- apparently adding a font into a shadowdom does not work, so add it to head -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="logview"></div>
    <div id="controls"></div>
    <script src="logview.js" async defer></script> <!-- Actual logic, logview.ts -->
    <script src="DropDownButton.js" async defer></script> <!-- Customelement, backed by DropDownButton.ts -->
</body>

</html>

Webpack config:
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin = require("html-inline-css-webpack-plugin").default;

module.exports = {
    mode: "development", // TODO: how should we switch this between development and production?
    devtool: false, // TODO: what is the correct setting here, to either do no transform or fast builds?
    entry: {
        dropdown: "./src/DropDownButton.ts",
        logview: "./src/logview.ts",
        //index: "./src/logview.html",
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css",
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "logview.html",
            template: "./src/logview.html",
            chunks: [],
            inlineSource: ".(js|css)$",
        }),
        new HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin(),//{filter: () => { return true; }}),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    //"style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                ],
                type: "asset/inline",
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ ".tsx", ".ts", ".js" ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        clean: true,
    },
};


Turns out that there is a new webpack5 plugin which does exactly what I want: https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin. (The turn over rate of new plugins and depreceated plugins for webpack is stunning for someone not in the field, half the answers I found where outdated since they use deprecated or webpack4 plugins).
Either way, here is a configuration which for webpack which takes a html file as shown above and inlines all js/css. Also js is build from ts as needed.
const path = require("path");
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require("html-bundler-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development", // TODO: how should we switch this between development and production?
    devtool: false, // TODO: what is the correct setting here, to either do no transform or fast builds?
    entry: {
        index: "./src/logview.html",
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
            css: { inline: true },
            js: { inline: true },
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
               oneOf: [
                    { // css modules
                        test: /\.module\.css$/,
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: "css-loader",
                                options: {
                                    exportType: "css-style-sheet", // <= for use in shadowdom with `adoptedStyleSheets`
                                    //esModule: true, // in case you need access to the mangled class names this helps, see the docs
                                    modules: {
                                        localIdentName: "[local]",// if used with a shadow dom writing templates without name mangling is easier, otherwise: [name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    { // vanilla css
                        use: [
                            "css-loader",
                        ],
                    }
            {
                 test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|webp|woff2?)$/i,
                 type: "asset/inline",
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ ".tsx", ".ts", ".js" ],
        extensionAlias: {
            ".js": [".ts", ".js"],
        },
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        clean: true,
    },
};

The configuration assumes that the following node packages are installed:
├── css-loader@7.1.1
├── html-bundler-webpack-plugin@3.12.0
├── ts-loader@9.5.1
├── tsc@2.0.4
├── typescript@5.4.5
├── webpack-cli@5.1.4
└── webpack@5.91.0

typing.d.ts
declare module '*.module.css'


I would complete the config. If you have images and/or fonts in CSS or HTML, then add the rule to inline them {test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|webp|woff2?)$/i, type: 'asset/inline'}.
All fonts, images will be inlined as base64 in inlined CSS or in HTML.

@biodiscus: seems like a very good addition to me, feel free to edit it in for easier readability. I found that css modules might not work when using them from typescript (first time I am trying to use those so I might do several things wrong). If I figure that out I will update this answer, otherwise I might ask a new question.

thanks to @biodiscus (auther of the plugin), we got a new version of the html-bundler-webpack-plugin which supports mixing normal css files and css modules. I updated the answer accordingly for completness sake, but this usecase is now also documented in the offical documentation.
